# got "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function" on production mode next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Got error below on build mode, (works fine in dev mode)

versions:

```
"next": "^13.5.1",
"react-froala-wysiwyg": "^4.1.3",
```

component code:

```
const FroalaEditorComponent = dynamic(
  async () => {
    const values = await Promise.all([
      import('react-froala-wysiwyg'),
      import('froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css'),
      import('froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css'),
      import('froala-editor/js/plugins.pkgd.min.js'),
      import('froala-editor/js/plugins/image.min.js'),
    ]);
    return values[0];
  },
  {
    loading: () => <Skeleton height={290} />,
    ssr: false,
  },
);
```

```
<FroalaEditorComponent
   config={config}
   model={value}
   onModelChange={onChange}
/>
```

errors: "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function"